# Batch rename files using mv and sed within a for loop results in exit code 64 - How do I correct the script?

Tags: for-loop, sed, terminal, echo, mv

I am attempting to rename several hundred folders to remove numbers that are prefixed to the folder name.  I seem to have gotten most of the way there, but my script does not quite work yet.  When I `echo` the commands created by the script instead of running those commands, everything looks fine.  The script:

```
for file in *
do
    echo mv "'"$file"'" $(echo "'"$file"'" | sed 's/[0-9]\{1,3\} //')
done
```

returns many lines of:

```
mv '123 filename' 'filename'
mv '99 another name' 'another name'
. . . etc.
```

If I take one of those lines and use on the command line, the folder is renamed appropriately.  If I remove the `echo` to actually run those `mv` commands, though, they do not work.  Instead, `mv` prints out the usage reminder that comes when you incorrectly enter the command in some way.

Why do the output commands work individually but not within the for loop?  How can I correct this script?

Comment: Welcome to SO Christopher!  I have edited your post to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, Brian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quoting looks oddball. The variable should be in double quotes, no more and no less.

Furthermore, you should avoid the brittle `$(echo ... | sed ...)`; this can be accomplished in pure shell:

```
for f in *; do
    g=${f#[0-9]}; g=${g#[0-9]}; g=${g#[0-9]}
    echo mv "$f" "${g# }"
done
```

Run with `sh -x` if you want to verify that the `echo` gets correct quoting. Then remove the `echo` to actually move.

The reason the output worked when copy/pasted is that the second level of quoting was actually necessary when copying the output from `echo`. A (risky, convoluted) workaround would have been to replace `echo` with `eval`.

Comment: The bash translation of the `echo|sed` could be: `shopt -s extglob; g=${f#[0-9]?([0-9])?([0-9]) }`

Comment: Many thanks, tripleee.  My oddball quoting and "brittle" approach both came from lots of trial, lots of error, and not much prior knowledge.  So far as the latter goes, I'll spend some time working out exactly what is happening in line two of your script (and in glenn jackman's).  In the abstract, I get that you're removing numbers one at a time from the start of `$f` by repeatedly modifying `$g`.  Just not sure why `${g#[0-9]}` does that yet; the `#` in there is new to me.

Comment: Substitutions are documented in the `bash` manual page, or e.g. at http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html